# Why Internet speed dropped after install VPN Software?

Tags: networking, vpn, network-adapter, windows-11

Due to my work I had to install several VPN software, however, I noticed that Windows 11 has created a dedicated network adapter for which it VPN programs and also for the Vmware and antivirus.

After installing this bunch of software then I realized my Internet connection has decreased its speed, even not being connected to either VPN.

And the most strange is the wifi connection is having a better quality over ethernet cable. Before installing all these VPN software I used to achieve 500 Mbps for download/upload, but now I am just getting 10 Mbps using the cable.

Regarding [Albim](https://superuser.com/users/201818/albin) question, I ran the command:

> Get-NetAdapter | sort name

```
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Bluetooth Network Conn... Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Netw...      25 Disabled     9C-DA-3E-14-55-2C         3 Mbps
Ethernet                  Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller           44 Up           80-FA-5B-33-DC-99        10 Mbps
Ethernet 2                Fortinet Virtual Ethernet Adapter (N...      24 Not Present  00-09-0F-FE-00-01          0 bps
Ethernet 3                Fortinet SSL VPN Virtual Ethernet Ad...       5 Not Present  00-09-0F-AA-00-01          0 bps
Ethernet 4                PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter               23 Disabled     02-50-41-00-00-01         2 Gbps
Ethernet 5                Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Cli...      18 Not Present  00-05-9A-3C-7A-00          0 bps
Ethernet 6                Sophos TAP Adapter                            8 Not Present  00-FF-2F-61-04-29          0 bps
Ethernet 7                Kaspersky Security Data Escort Adapter       14 Not Present  00-FF-93-E4-F1-19          0 bps
Local Area Connection     PPPoP WAN Adapter                             9 Not Present  00-00-00-00-00-00          0 bps
Local Area Connection* 11 Check Point Virtual Network Adapter ...      17 Not Present  54-92-E0-9D-85-12          0 bps
VMware Network Adapte...1 VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for ...      16 Not Present  00-50-56-C0-00-01          0 bps
VMware Network Adapte...8 VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for ...      22 Not Present  00-50-56-C0-00-08          0 bps
Wi-Fi                     Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160          26 Up           9C-DA-3E-14-55-28       325 Mbps
```

Then I could realised that the collum "LinkSpeed" is shown as 10 Mbps, therefore I tried to change it by:

Ethernet Propertis>> Client for Microsoft Networking>> Configure>> Advanced>> Speed & Duplex
Changed from "Auto Negotiation" to "1.0 Gbps Full Duplex"

After this change I could not connect into the ethernet cable anymore, also after running again the command: Get-NetAdapter | sort name
I saw no change at the LinkSpeed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6h5Z.png)

How to I get my internet connection back to normal.

[image]

Comment: Please list the programs you installed. Was it just VPN or antivirus software as well? What's the link's speed (`Get-NetAdapter | sort name` in Powershell)? Please add this information to your question. Note: this could also be something unrelated to the software installations.

Comment: Hi @Albin, thanks for your comments! I've just updated my question.

Comment: My first guess would be an issue with the cable or the port on the router or your PC. Try to find out where the problem is located a little better: can you try to connect the PC to a different switch, use a different cable or connect a different wired device that you confirmed as working to the cable, etc.?

Comment: I've tested the cable connection in other PC, and there is no issue with cable.

Comment: the cable is only one possible component causing the fault